# what is the difference between SliverAppBar and SliverPersistentHeader in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

What is the main difference between SliverAppBar and SliverPersistentHeader ?

What differ most in terms of their usage purpose ?

Comment: `SliverPersistentHeader` can be used to create a `SliverAppBar` with custom behavior. Check the link for more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3-WdYBrEDc&t=66s&ab_channel=CodeWithAndrea

Answer (score 6):

**SliverAppBar :**

`SliverAppBar` is a Material Design widget in flutter which gives scrollable or collapsible app-bar. The word Sliver is given to scrollable areas here. `SliverAppBar` basically gives us means to create an app-bar that can change appearance, blend in the background, or even disappear as we scroll.

**SliverPersistentHeader :**

A sliver whose size varies when the sliver is scrolled to the edge of the viewport opposite the sliver's `GrowthDirection`. In the normal case of a `CustomScrollView` with no centered sliver, this sliver will vary its size when scrolled to the leading edge of the viewport.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3-WdYBrEDc) Video also. for `SliverAppBar` and `SliverPersistentHeader`

Refer `SliverAppBar` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Refer `SliverPersistentHeader` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html#:%7E:text=SliverPersistentHeader%20class%20Null%20safety,leading%20edge%20of%20the%20viewport.)